# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8)

Tags: android, spring-boot, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I have created an android jetpack compose and springboot project. For running the springboot project I have injected retrofit and dagger-hilt dependencies.

This is the error I am getting in the project while running the project:-

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.validateKotlinAndJavaHasSameTargetCompatibility(Tasks.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:722)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:530)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:450)
```

I have this build.gradle(Project):-

```
        buildscript {
        ext {
            compose_ui_version = '1.4.3'
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
        id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
    }

this is build.gradle(Module):-

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.studentdemo'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studentdemo"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.21"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3'

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.27.0"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.6.0-alpha01"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.18.0"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.2"

    //Camera
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-beta01"

    //Retrofit
    // these two lines are added for retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"

//Dagger-Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

This is the code that I am using.

StudentFormViewModel:-

```
@HiltViewModel
class StudentFormViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val studentApi: StudentApi,
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : ViewModel() {

    fun addStudent(
        id: Int,
        name: String,
        SDate: String,
        entryTime: String,
        status: Boolean,
        holidayStatus: String,
        imageUri: Uri
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val imageInputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
            val imageBytes = imageInputStream?.readBytes()
            if (imageBytes != null) {
                val imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                    "image",
                    "image.jpg",
                    imageBytes.toRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                )
                val namePart = name.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
                val SDatePart = SDate.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
                val entryTimePart = entryTime.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
                val holidayStatusPart = holidayStatus.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)

                val response = studentApi.addStudent(
                    id,
                    namePart,
                    SDatePart,
                    entryTimePart,
                    status,
                    holidayStatusPart,
                    imagePart
                )
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    // Handle successful response
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NetworkModule:-

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideStudentApi(retrofit: Retrofit): StudentApi {
        return retrofit.create(StudentApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

StudentApi:-

```
interface StudentApi {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/students/{id}")
    suspend fun addStudent(
        @Path("id") id: Int,
        @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
        @Part("SDate") SDate: RequestBody,
        @Part("entryTime") entryTime: RequestBody,
        @Part("status") status: Boolean,
        @Part("holidayStatus") holidayStatus: RequestBody,
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Response<String>
}
```

I have tried changing this build.gradle(Module) from this:-

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

To this(18 version) latest:-

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '18'
    }
```

The problem is after using the dagger-hilt functions in the project. If I do not use them there is no problem. there is no problem with the dependencies.

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#kotlin) is the documentation I referred to implement in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in the build.gradle(Module):-

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
```